# How did the various meanings of "fare" come about?

Tags: meaning, etymology, word-usage

The word 'fare' has many different usages that are seemingly unrelated to its root meaning given in the dictionary: "to go or travel".

> Bus fare
>   - *the fee for getting on the bus*
>
> Thanksgiving fare
>   - *the foods prepared on Thanksgiving*
>
> How are you faring?
>   - *how are you doing?*

Nowadays, it seems to be used to mean everything except "to go or travel". I have never heard anyone say anything like "I fared to Europe on vacation". How did this come about?

Comment: As an aside, the money that a person pays to ride a bus, taxi, etc., is also called "carfare." http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carfare

Comment: I found some (ahem) *fairly* detailed information on the etymology of the various meanings of "fare" by googling "fare etymology".  What has your research uncovered?

Answer (score 1):

OED's first definition is apparently the oldest sense (but now obsolete)...

> 1a: *a going, journeying; course, passage, way; voyage.* (cf [thoroughfare](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=thoroughfare))

...which transparently leads to the still current sense...

> 4b: *cost of conveyance (now only of persons; formerly also of goods); passage money*

I should point out that I consider usages such as *How are you faring?* to be dated, bordering on archaic. The other primary sense that's still current *(fare = food, provisions)* seems to have been arrived at through these (now also obsolete) meanings...

> 6a: *mode of proceeding, bearing, demeanour; appearance, aspect.*
>
> 6b: *a proceeding, action; ‘doings’; hence, fighting.*
>
> 6c: *display, pomp; commotion, uproar, fuss*
>
> 7: *Condition, state, welfare; state of things, prosperity, success.*

...ending up with OED's final definition for the noun usage...

> 8: *food, regarded with reference to its quality;*
>   *supply or provision of food, regarded as abundant or scanty.*

I think that final sense arises through *mode, aspect* in the context of journeys which would be long enough to need *provisions* - of a quantity and/or quality commensurate with the *fare = price paid* for the *fare = journey* by the *fare = paying passenger*.

Note that from the point of view of the person/company providing the transport/provisions, both the paying traveller and whatever he will need to eat are *things that have to be transported* that wouldn't normally be called "cargo" (because they're not for sale at the end of the journey).